# Событие в элементе CheckedListBox

Tags: winforms, c++-cli

Есть обычный `CheckedListBox`, в нем есть один элемент - `CheckBox`, мне нужно отловить событие при клике мышкой не по `CheckedListBox`, а именно по `CheckBox`, который в нем находится, пробую так:

```
private: System::Void checkedListBox1_MouseEnter(System::Object^ sender, System::EventArgs^ e)
{
    if (checkedListBox1->Items[0]->GetType()->GetEvent(L"Click"))
    {
        MessageBox::Show("Click!");
    }
}
```

Comment: Используйте событие [ItemCheck](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.windows.forms.checkedlistbox.itemcheck(v=vs.110).aspx).

Comment: @Alexander Petrov - а если я не создаю этот чекбокс заранее, а он создается по нажатию на кнопку?

Comment: В параметре `ItemCheckEventArgs` индекс изменённого элемента. Смотрите пример кода на C# - там всё расписано.

Comment: @Alexander Petrov - можно ссылочку на пример?

Comment: В Вашем коде нет C++, но есть C++/CLI. Пожалуйста, прекратите добавлять тег языка, которого в вопросе нет.